# How to compare date in python?

Tags: python, datetime

How to check datetime in python3?

Both date and time are same but in 'b' there is no zero.

```
  a = '2020-09-08 05:09:02'
  b = '2020-9-8 5:9:2'
  if a == b:
     print("yes")
  else:
     print("no")

 Expected Output:
   yes
```

Comment: have a look at the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) standard lib and especially [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can turn them into `datetime` objects and compare them

```py
import datetime as dt
a = '2020-09-08 05:09:02'
b = '2020-9-8 5:9:2'
a_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
b_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if a_dt == b_dt:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```